# Multiple charts in EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

This question will most probably get downvoted, but I'll ask anyways since I can't find an answer elsewhere. I'm working on a data processing application which processes a large amount of data and writes them to an excel file using `EPPlus`. I now have to create some graphs with the data in the excel programmatically through `EPPlus`. Since I'm not really an expert on EPPlus, I'm looking for some online resource or documentation that could help me with charts. I've searched online but I couldn't find a single place, where they list all possible chart types that could be made with `EPPLus` and how. If anyone knows of some online resource where they all list everything related to charts via `EPPlus`, it would really help me. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a perfectly reasonable question.  I agree, documentation is fairly light - but hey its free so I am happy with whatever they can give us :).

By far, the most helpful thing I have done with Epplus is downloading the source code and reverse engineering it.  When I try to figure out a particular chart type I look at this:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/Drawing/Chart/ExcelChart.cs

Particularly, look at the enum `eChartType`:

```
public enum eChartType
{
    Area3D=-4098,
    AreaStacked3D=78,
    AreaStacked1003D=79,
    BarClustered3D= 60,
    BarStacked3D=61,
    BarStacked1003D=62,
    Column3D=-4100,
    ColumnClustered3D=54,
    ColumnStacked3D=55,
    ColumnStacked1003D=56,
    Line3D=-4101,
    Pie3D=-4102,
    PieExploded3D=70,
    Area=1,
    AreaStacked=76,
    AreaStacked100=77,
    BarClustered=57,
    BarOfPie=71,
    BarStacked=58,
    BarStacked100=59,
    Bubble=15,
    Bubble3DEffect=87,
    ColumnClustered=51,
    ColumnStacked=52,
    ColumnStacked100=53,
    ConeBarClustered=102,
    ConeBarStacked=103,
    ConeBarStacked100=104,
    ConeCol=105,
    ConeColClustered=99,
    ConeColStacked=100,
    ConeColStacked100=101,
    CylinderBarClustered=95,
    CylinderBarStacked=96,
    CylinderBarStacked100=97,
    CylinderCol=98,
    CylinderColClustered=92,
    CylinderColStacked=93,
    CylinderColStacked100=94,
    Doughnut=-4120,
    DoughnutExploded=80,
    Line=4,
    LineMarkers=65,
    LineMarkersStacked=66,
    LineMarkersStacked100=67,
    LineStacked=63,
    LineStacked100=64,
    Pie=5,
    PieExploded=69,
    PieOfPie=68,
    PyramidBarClustered=109,
    PyramidBarStacked=110,
    PyramidBarStacked100=111,
    PyramidCol=112,
    PyramidColClustered=106,
    PyramidColStacked=107,
    PyramidColStacked100=108,
    Radar=-4151,
    RadarFilled=82,
    RadarMarkers=81,
    StockHLC=88,
    StockOHLC=89,
    StockVHLC=90,
    StockVOHLC=91,
    Surface=83,
    SurfaceTopView=85,
    SurfaceTopViewWireframe=86,
    SurfaceWireframe=84,
    XYScatter=-4169,
    XYScatterLines=74,
    XYScatterLinesNoMarkers=75,
    XYScatterSmooth=72,
    XYScatterSmoothNoMarkers=73
}
```

As for "how", this the tougher part.  But fortunately they all follow a consistent pattern so usually if can figure it out fairly quickly with a little trial and error.  Usually starts with something like:

```
var chart1 = wsContent.Drawings.AddChart("Chart1", eChartType.XYScatterLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is indeed not really complete at that point. I would suggest look at the small list at: http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/118053 ("Chart Types).
Also, the demo buids may help and lastly, their sourcecode is online. Start searching for a known chartttype and take a look at what other values are allowed.